# Difference in use of "from" and "from .. on" when referring to a period in future

Tags: prepositions, future-constructions

Assuming we talk about some period in future, which continues (either indefinitely or infinitely long) is there any difference in use between "from" and "from .. on"? E.g:

1. `The card is valid from June 20th`
2. `The card is valid from June 20th on`

Are both variants equally valid and can be used interchangeably in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

People often add the prepositions **on** or **onwards** to such statements for emphasis.

Sentence 1 has the merit of crispness and brevity. But you will frequently come across the use of the final preposition after a date or time, more in speech than in communications from financial institutions.